# Why is it called "Cloud"?

Tags: cloud

Yes, as you might guess, I want to ask about Cloud-computing. I doubt that why it's called that. Which characteristics of it made that name?

Comment: Because calling it "swamp computing" didn't sit well with focus groups.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not within the scope of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing):

> The term cloud is used as a metaphor
>   for the Internet, based on the cloud
>   drawing used in the past to represent
>   the telephone network, and later to
>   depict the Internet in computer
>   network diagrams as an abstraction of
>   the underlying infrastructure it
>   represents.

Comment: Am I the only one who used to cringe every time I saw a complex hierarchical drawing of some internal network and then it ended with a line to a simple cloud label "web" as if it was just some sort of a small convenience, minor issue and an afterthought in the whole network :)

Comment: @Esko.  Nope, it's not just you.  There was a time in around 2000-2001 when every single PowerPoint presentation had to feature that little cloud at some point.  It was as ubiquitous as the puzzled Screen Bean scratching his head.

Answer (score 4):

It means nothing. Just a nice word and now it's hot....

Here is a quote from the same WIKI as above:

> Larry Ellison, CEO of Oracle
>   Corporation has stated that cloud
>   computing has been defined as
>   "everything that we already do" and
>   that it will have no effect except to
>   "change the wording on some of our
>   ads"

Answer (score 3):

Because it's a nebulous concept?  Because it has been generated by a lot of hot air?  Or just because it obscures the details of the infrastructure?